# problem with upstart: Job failed to start

Tags: linux, upstart

I got always an error message that my upstart script doesn't start.

start: Job failed to start

My script is:

```
description "Tagger Version 2"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
respawn limit 2 5

pre-start script  

mkdir -p /run/lemmatization/Lemmatizer  
chown nobody /run/lemmatization -R  

end script

setgid nogroup
setuid  nobody

exec some_shell_skript.sh
```

The problem must be in the pre-start section, since everythink works fine if I comment it out.

Comment: Check the logfile `/var/log/upstart/<your_job_name.log>` for more infos/error messages and post them please in your question.

Comment: ah, thanks a lot I got the following messages: 
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/lemmatization': Permission denied
but I thought the script runs with root permission, doesn't it?

Comment: yes, but in your upstart job I see setuid and setgid. They are there to run a job as another user/group. And `nobody` has no permissions to create the directory

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very helpful comments. Ok, i see the problem. I want to start the process with user nobody but for the creation of the directory I need root permissions. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: See my answer, I described the upstart job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to execute the pre-start stanza as root and the start stanza as nobody you have to use `sudo`. Try it with that upstart job:

```
description "Tagger Version 2"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
respawn limit 2 5

pre-start script  

mkdir -p /run/lemmatization/Lemmatizer  
chown nobody /run/lemmatization -R  

end script

exec sudo -u nobody -g nogroup some_shell_skript.sh
```

As you see I removed the setuid/setgid part completely and used `sudo` instead to execute your script as another user.